# Linux files gone after reboot

Tags: debian, partitioning, data-loss

i got a raspberrypi with raspbian on it and today i noticed that the file i write to the server are not persistent anymore. Couldn't find any errors in the log reagarding to that. The only thing i could find was with fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 119.08 GiB, 127865454592 bytes, 249737216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xeb794bf4

Device         Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192    532479    524288   256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      532480 249737215 249204736 118.8G 83 Linux
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
```

As far as i know this should be mbr and not gpt but for some reason it says that the gpt backup table is corrupt. I tried testdisk and fixparts but no matter what i do after a reboot the problem persists.
Do you have any idea where i can look for errors or fix it? If possible i'd like to avoid a reinstall

Any help appreciated